# Updating json model and retaining/converting existing data - Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a data model which looks as such:

```
struct MacroLog : Codable {
    var date: Date = Date()
    var type: MacroType
    var beforeValue: Int
    var afterValue: Int
    var description: String
    var isOverwrite: Bool = false
    
    func valueDifference() -> Int {
        return afterValue - beforeValue
    }
}
```

And I need to update it with adding a timestamp property as such:

```
struct MacroLog : Codable {
    let timestamp: Date
    var date: Date = Date()
    var type: MacroType
    var beforeValue: Int
    var afterValue: Int
    var description: String
    var isOverwrite: Bool = false
    
    func valueDifference() -> Int {
        return afterValue - beforeValue
    }
}
```

What would I need to do, to have my existing MacroLog entities retained or converted to the new model data? I know it stays retained so this is basically me asking how I properly manage making model changes of any kind in these situations.

I update new entries the following way:

```
private func updateLogs(logs: [MacroLog]) {
    
    var logsData = Data()
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        logsData = try encoder.encode(logs)
        
        _ = (logsData as NSData).write(to: fileUrl as URL, atomically: true)
    } catch {
        print("failed - \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Most straightforward solution is to make timestamp optional

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was solved by the answer in the comment about making the timestamp optional. That way, all my previous log entries are retained and loaded going forward.